# angular spa app not working ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

In Angular ngResource is not functionning correctly. I have added the script reference. The problem is that when I add the dependencie to ngResourc blank pages are displayed. What should I do?

```
/*var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('todoFactory', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/meetups');
});*/

angular.module('myApp').controller('loginController',
  ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService',
  function ($scope, $location, AuthService) {

    $scope.login = function () {

      // initial values
      $scope.error = false;
      $scope.disabled = true;

      // call login from service
      AuthService.login($scope.loginForm.username, $scope.loginForm.password)
        // handle success
        .then(function () {
          $location.path('/');
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.loginForm = {};
        })
        // handle error
        .catch(function () {
          $scope.error = true;
          $scope.errorMessage = "Invalid username and/or password";
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.loginForm = {};
        });    
    };    
}]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('logoutController',
  ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService', '$resource',
  function ($scope, $location, AuthService) {

    $scope.logout = function () {

      // call logout from service
      AuthService.logout()
        .then(function () {
          $location.path('/login');
        });    
    };    

/*    
 $scope.posts = [];
   $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', create_at: ''};

    $scope.afficher = function(){
      $scope.newPost.created_at = Date.now();
      $scope.posts.push($scope.newPost);
      $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};
  };

*/
   $scope.meetups = [];
  /*var Meetup = $resource('/api/meetups');

  Meetup.query(function (results) {
    $scope.meetups = results;
  });

  $scope.meetups = []

  $scope.createMeetup = function () {
    var meetup = new Meetup();
    meetup.name = $scope.meetupName;
    meetup.$save(function (result) {
      $scope.meetups.push(result);
      $scope.meetupName = '';
    });
  }*/    
}]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('registerController',
  ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService',
  function ($scope, $location, AuthService) {

    $scope.register = function () {

      // initial values
      $scope.error = false;
      $scope.disabled = true;

      // call register from service
      AuthService.register($scope.registerForm.username, $scope.registerForm.password)
        // handle success
        .then(function () {
          $location.path('/login');
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.registerForm = {};
        })
        // handle error
        .catch(function () {
          $scope.error = true;
          $scope.errorMessage = "Something went wrong!";
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.registerForm = {};
        });    
    };    
}]);
```

I will add code on demand

Comment: What does the console say?

Answer (score 0):

It's always better in such cases to open a debug window (F12 or command+shift+I), toggle Console tab and check what it says. Blank page can de displayed within several circumstances.

Also you can try to complete the commented-out version of your code to avoid new module declaration like this^
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

```
app.factory('todoFactory', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/meetups');
});

app.controller('loginController',
  ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService',
  function ($scope, $location, AuthService) {

    $scope.login = function () {

      // initial values
      $scope.error = false;
      $scope.disabled = true;

      // call login from service
      AuthService.login($scope.loginForm.username, $scope.loginForm.password)
        // handle success
        .then(function () {
          $location.path('/');
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.loginForm = {};
        })
        // handle error
        .catch(function () {
          $scope.error = true;
          $scope.errorMessage = "Invalid username and/or password";
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.loginForm = {};
        });

    };

}]);

app.controller('logoutController',
  ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService', '$resource',
  function ($scope, $location, AuthService) {

    $scope.logout = function () {

      // call logout from service
      AuthService.logout()
        .then(function () {
          $location.path('/login');
        });

    };


/*

 $scope.posts = [];
   $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', create_at: ''};

    $scope.afficher = function(){
      $scope.newPost.created_at = Date.now();
      $scope.posts.push($scope.newPost);
      $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};
  };

*/
   $scope.meetups = [];
  /*var Meetup = $resource('/api/meetups');

  Meetup.query(function (results) {
    $scope.meetups = results;
  });

  $scope.meetups = []

  $scope.createMeetup = function () {
    var meetup = new Meetup();
    meetup.name = $scope.meetupName;
    meetup.$save(function (result) {
      $scope.meetups.push(result);
      $scope.meetupName = '';
    });
  }*/






}]);

app.controller('registerController',
  ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService',
  function ($scope, $location, AuthService) {

    $scope.register = function () {

      // initial values
      $scope.error = false;
      $scope.disabled = true;

      // call register from service
      AuthService.register($scope.registerForm.username, $scope.registerForm.password)
        // handle success
        .then(function () {
          $location.path('/login');
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.registerForm = {};
        })
        // handle error
        .catch(function () {
          $scope.error = true;
          $scope.errorMessage = "Something went wrong!";
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.registerForm = {};
        });

    };

}]);
```

Comment: 10q for your reply there no logs in the console. please help me

Comment: Quite strange. Try to refresh spa page after you've opened debug tools. In some browsers debug tools won't display anything until your page will be refreshed. In addition you check network tab (JS section) to determine if your page actually received new library from server.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('logoutController',
  ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService', '$resource',
  function ($scope, $location, AuthService,**$resource**) {

    $scope.logout = function () {

      // call logout from service
      AuthService.logout()
        .then(function () {
          $location.path('/login');
        });    
    };
```

you havent add the resource to your function

Comment: remove the ** from the $resource sides

Comment: 10x but no luck here still blank pages... can you help am trying to make 2 app in one page instead here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240701/declaring-2-app-in-angular-doesnt-work

Comment: have you added ng-app to your html tag or any parent tag and ng-controller and for factory it is better to use $q and promise?